# TFS : Local PC Name is getting added, while connecting to TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

When I am trying to connect TFS server in Visual Studio 2013, my local PC name is getting added to TFS client credentials, which I don't want to be added. Am I missing any configuration on the same?

For your reference, I am attaching screenshot for the same and highlighted the local pcname.

[screenshot of the TFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d8Ni.png)

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are using **`/`** in `MEDISOL/raja.esakki`.

VS may treat this as a user name, for local users to connect to TFS, it will contain machine name.

If you are working on a domain and the domain name is **MEDISOL**, you should use `\` instead `/`

Try to use `MEDISOL\raja.esakki` in the pop-up dialog and test again.